# RegionPlot3D doesn't evaluate a set of conditions

Tags: regions

A huge set of conditions

```
    cond={1440 (eta + 2 xsi) (9.81 + 0.003969 (1 + zeta)) >= 
  114.307 (1 + zeta), 
 114.307 (1 + zeta) >= 
  1440 (eta - 2 xsi) (9.81 + 0.003969 (1 + zeta)), 
 1440 (9.81 (2 + eta - 2 xsi) + 
     0.0068431 (-11.6 + 0.58 (eta - 2 xsi)) (1 + zeta)) >= 0, 
 1440 (9.81 (-2 + eta + 2 xsi) + 
     0.0068431 (-11.6 + 0.58 (eta + 2 xsi)) (1 + zeta)) <= 
  0, -783.333 <= -0.275369 (78.2399 eta + 1560.9 (-1 + xsi) - 
     3.90224 (1 + xsi)), -0.275369 (78.2399 eta + 1560.9 (-1 + xsi) - 
     3.90224 (1 + xsi)) <= 783.333, -783.333 <= 
  0.249143 (78.2399 eta + 1560.9 (-1 + xsi) - 3.90224 (1 + xsi)), 
 0.249143 (78.2399 eta + 1560.9 (-1 + xsi) - 3.90224 (1 + xsi)) <= 
  783.333, 2482.76 (0.000443649 (78.2399 eta + 1560.9 (-1 + xsi) - 
        3.90224 (1 + xsi)) + 0.0184162 (1 + zeta) - 
     0.232 (eta + 2 xsi) (9.81 + 0.003969 (1 + zeta))) <= 0, 
 2482.76 (-0.000443649 (78.2399 eta + 1560.9 (-1 + xsi) - 
        3.90224 (1 + xsi)) + 0.0184162 (1 + zeta) - 
     0.232 (eta + 2 xsi) (9.81 + 0.003969 (1 + zeta))) <= 0, 
 2482.76 (-0.000401397 (78.2399 eta + 1560.9 (-1 + xsi) - 
        3.90224 (1 + xsi)) + 
     0.4 (-0.0460404 (1 + zeta) + 
        0.58 (eta - 2 xsi) (9.81 + 0.003969 (1 + zeta)))) <= 0, 
 2482.76 (0.000401397 (78.2399 eta + 1560.9 (-1 + xsi) - 
        3.90224 (1 + xsi)) + 
     0.4 (-0.0460404 (1 + zeta) + 
        0.58 (eta - 2 xsi) (9.81 + 0.003969 (1 + zeta)))) <= 0}
```

define a region in 3D

I would like to create a `RegionPlot3D`

```
RegionPlot3D[ AllTrue[cond], {xsi, 0, 1}, {eta, -1, 1}, {zeta, -1, 20} ]
```

but Mathematica doesn't evaluate.

What could be the reason ?
Is there a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: `RegionPlot3D[And @@ cond, {xsi, 0, 1}, {eta, -1, 1}, {zeta, -1, 20}]` ?

Comment: @Syed Such  a simple solution, thank you very much. Couldn't step away from  my AllTrue attempt...

Comment: @Syed Followup problem: Is it possible to extract the "Volume"  as an implicit region from a given `RegionPlot3D ` ? Thank You!

Comment: `reg = ImplicitRegion[And @@ cond, {xsi, eta, zeta}];` and `Volume@reg` gives `3.11594` and the `RegionMeasure[reg, 3]` gives the same result, albeit with some delay. I don't have enough insight to say if it is correct, but you can provide feedback. Thanks.

Comment: @Syed Thanks for your fast response. Unfortuantely `Region[reg]` only shows a blanc cell.

Comment: I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyxHI.png) on v12.2.0 on Win7-x64.

Comment: Thanks my MMA version 12.2 is the same , but on Win10-x64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RegionPlot3D[And @@ cond, {xsi, 0, 1}, {eta, -1, 1}, {zeta, -1, 20}]
```

OR

```
RegionPlot3D[
 AllTrue[cond, # == True &], {xsi, 0, 1}, {eta, -1, 1}, {zeta, -1, 
  20}]
```

[image]

Comment: `RegionPlot3D[
 AllTrue[cond, Identity], {xsi, 0, 1}, {eta, -1, 1}, {zeta, -1, 20}]` would also work and look less awkward.